# Xcode: Inherit `configuration`s from parent project - not possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcconfig

## TL;DR

Is it possible to inherit custom configurations from parent project? No, not asking about inheriting some target setting.

## Configurations and preprocessor macros/flags

Every project in Xcode is initialized with the two standard *configurations* called `Debug` and `Release`. It is a quite common pattern to setup a `DEBUG` flag using the setting under the display name `Preprocessor Macros` in Build Settings for a target (in `.pbxproj` this is called `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`), which can be read from Objective-C code like this.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   print("DEBUG flag set")
#else 
   print("No debug flag!")
#endif
```

This also works in Swift, but then we have to use `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` and declare it like this: 
 `-D DEBUG` 
and reading the variable value just like we did in the Objective C code above.

## Many projects => xcconfig files

**My app consists of an xcworkspace with a main project and several projects as dependencies.** Let's call the projects my app is dependent on *frameworks*. Since I have several frameworks I do not want to have to setup build settings several times on.

Thus I am using `xcconfig` files. I have a main config, that is the config file for the main project, let's call it `Main.xcconfig`. I have another config file called `Framework.xcconfig` which starts with the line `#include "Main.xcconfig"`, thus inheriting settings from `Main`. And of course I setup each *framework* to make use of said `Framework.xcconfig` file.

It is very convenient to declare the `DEBUG` flag when we have these config file, in `Main.xcconfig` we add:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[config=Debug] = -D DEBUG
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug] = DEBUG
```

And thus declaring the `DEBUG` flag for the *configuration* `Debug` for the main project and the framework projects (since `Framework.xcconfig` inherits from `Main.xcconfig`...).

## Custom configurations

What if we want to be able to profile the app but with the `DEBUG` flag set? Profiling should be done with the same optimisation flags as `Release`. But we absolutely do not want to set the `DEBUG` flag for `Release` builds.

Why not create a new *configuration*, let's call it `Profiling`. **Here comes the problem!** Of course we should create this new *configuration* to the main project. Then we edit our scheme and for *Profile* and under 
*Build Configuration* we chose the new *configuration* `Profiling`.

Now we can set the `DEBUG` flag for `Profiling` in the `Main.xcconfig` file.

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[config=Debug] = -D DEBUG // we keep this
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug] = DEBUG // we keep this
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[config=Profiling] = -D DEBUG
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Profiling] = DEBUG
```

We try running the simulator and we see *"No debug flag!"*, which is expected since for running we are using the `Debug` configuration and thus not declaring the `DEBUG` flag.

So we try profiling and start some Instruments measurement and [open the console](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-9390.html). There we see the message *"DEBUG flag set"*

It works, great!

## Configurations are NOT inherited from parent project

We just checked against the `DEBUG` flag in the Main project. What happens if we in some of our frameworks want to check against our flags. So we try the `#ifdef DEBUG` in some framework. That works, since all frameworks have the *configuration* `Debug`, since it is default for all project (together with `Release`).

Then we try `#ifdef DEBUG` in one of our framework projects and start profiling using Instruments again. And now we see the message *"No debug flag!"*

**Oh no!**
It is not working! Why not?! Well I do not **know** but the only reasonable conclusion must be that our projects added as dependencies - our frameworks - **do not inherit the** `Profiling` *configuration* from the Main project.

For me this is unbelievable... It feels like a flaw in Xcode.

## Bad solution

I don't know of any other solution than adding the same *configuration* `Profiling` to all framework project (at least for frameworks where I know I want to check against that flag). **But this feels like such an ugly solution!**. I have at least 10 frameworks and it feels really ugly to have to add a certain *configuration* to each framework.

## Alternative (terrible!) solution

Yes of course another solution would be to use the `Release` *configuration* for profiling, and declaring the `DEBUG` flag in `Main.xcconfig` like this:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[config=Release] = -D DEBUG
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Release] = DEBUG
```

But since we want to be able to check against `DEBUG` flag in framework we need to add the two lines above, declaring the flag, to `Frameworks.xcconfig` as well.

And of course use the `Release` *configuration* for profiling as *Build Configuration* for the scheme.

Then we can add a new *configuration* called `AppStore` to our Main project, and only the Main project and use that for archiving the app. So far so good?

### [IT'S A TRAP!](http://67.media.tumblr.com/8ca77f44f85aa31e360438611b48a877/tumblr_nic8gbOGSO1u27pz3o1_1280.jpg)

No this is not a good idea! Because I just said that the *configurations* are **not** inherited between project and parent project. Thus our frameworks will not inherit this new `AppStore` *configuration*, so when the frameworks get built/archived I have seen them "fallback" to the `Release` *configuration* (not sure if you can chose "default"/"fallback" *configuration* somewhere? Maybe it will fallback to the one you used as base for the new *configuration*?).

But since we just added declaration of the `DEBUG` flag for the *configuration* `Release` for the Main project and all our frameworks, and it is the `Release` *configuration* that is used for all our frameworks when we archive the app => **our production app will include debug code!**. This is highly unwanted and potentially dangerous.

## Good solution?

I know of none... Do you? Wouldn't it be great if *configurations* would be inherited from parent project? That would solve everything! Apple... pretty please?

Comment: You can inherit the configurations from the parent by using the special variable `$(inherited)`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @macmoonshine Are you not confusing things here? I believe you are think of inherited target settings, for a certain key, e.g. `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) DEBUG`. I am not using target settings directly. I am using `xcconfig` files and thus that would translate to `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[Profiling] = $(inherited) DEBUG`. The problems is that the *configuration* `Profiling` is not available for our frameworks. It is a catch 22. It is the inheritance **of configurations** I am after! Not inheritance of a certain target build setting (like `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`).

Comment: `<SOME_SETTING>[config=<MY_CONFIGURATION>] = <SOME_VALUE>` in `.xcconfig` file OR equivalent `<SOME_SETTING>= <SOME_VALUE>` for the row `MY_CONFIGURATION` in `Target Settings` **is not possible** if `MY_CONFIGURATION` does not exist for said target (project). It is self explanatory for the `Target Settings` case (i.e. when not using `.xcconfig` files), because there is no row for `MY_CONFIGURATION`! And in the `.xcconfig` files the [config=<MY_CONFIGURATION>] just fails, since it does not exist. **Once again, how can I make sure to inherit MY_CONFIGURATION from parent project**?

Comment: @Sajjon did you find a solution or a workaround since ?

Comment: @Mosbah no unfortunately I did not

Comment: This is proof that Apple does not care

Answer (score 1):

As workaround: Create xconfig files per project and global ones. In the project xconfig files include the global one via

#include "path/to/File.xcconfig"

Hope this help